# Sencha Charts error "Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, sencha-touch-2

My app runs fine in development environ.

When I run build production, there are no errors.

When I view the production version in browser, I get the following error when the app should be producing charts:

> "Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"

When I debug, I see this error:

> : TypeError
>   get stack: function () { [native code] }
>   message: "Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"
>   set stack: function () { [native code] }
>   **proto**: Error
>   arguments: Arguments[2]
>   0: "series.gauge"
>   1: Object
>   angleField: "CurrentValue"
>   chart: Ext.apply.create.g
>   colorSet: Array[2]
>   donut: 30
>   margin: 10
>   maximum: 120
>   minimum: 0
>   position: "gauge"
>   steps: 10
>   type: "gauge"
>   **proto**: Object
>   callee: function (){var j=arguments[0],i=g.call(arguments,1),k=j,l,h;if(typeof j!="function"){h=this.get(j)}else{h=j}if(!h){l=this.getNameByAlias(j);if(l){j=l;h=this.get(j)}}if(!h){l=this.getNameByAlternate(j);if(l){j=l;h=this.get(j)}}if(!h){Ext.syncRequire(j);h=this.get(j)}return this.getInstantiator(i.length)(h,i)}
>   length: 2
>   **proto**: Object
>   h: function (){return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)}
>   i: Array[1]
>   0: Object
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array[0]
>   j: "Ext.chart.series.Gauge"
>   k: "series.gauge"
>   l: "Ext.chart.series.Gauge"

Ext.chart.series.Gauge is listed in my requires statement, as is Ext.chart.series.Series

I have tried creating the gauge using exactly the same code as exampled in the api docs, but still have the same problem.

This error is not there in the development version, only after I run a production build. I have ran the build using debug flags, to create a build log, but no errors were detailed. The error doesn't exists in a native build.

Sencha Touch 2.2.1
Sencha Cmd 3.1.2.342

**UPDATED**

I did a testing build. (That doesn't minify.) When my testing build app crashes, debugger goes straight to line 4552 of app.js, which is

```
return superMethod.apply(this, args || noArgs);
```

The whole function is:

```
callSuper: function(args) {
        var method,
            superMethod = (method = this.callSuper.caller) && ((method = method.$owner ? method : method.caller) && method.$owner.superclass[method.$name]);


        return superMethod.apply(this, args || noArgs);
    },
```

so any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: You need to build your application for production, but without compression (set `build.compression.yui=0` in `.sencha/app/production.properties`, and possibly disable `build.optimize` too). Hope that the problems replicates under those conditions, and then you'll be able to debug and figure out what's really going on in Ext.

Comment: I don't have any of those values in myappfolder/.sencha/app/production.properties

Comment: Oh? I'm not so used to Sencha CMD, but mine (Sencha CMD 3.2.something) has generated these values (with `compression.yui` set to 1) when the app was created. Try to add them yourself, I feel they should work anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question with new info